# GridFSFileInfo syntax for query GridFS

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

all.
I have a file, that was uploaded with custom metadata to MongoDB(GridFS) via C# driver 2.1rc1.
For uploading, I use:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
                var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");
                var mongoCollection = db.GetCollection<testFiles>("Files");

                //Initializing GdridFS conection
                GridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);


                //Uploading received file to GridFS with metadata
                await bucket.UploadFromStreamAsync
                (sourceFileProperties.FileName, sourceFile, new GridFSUploadOptions
                    {
                        Metadata = new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "FileName", sourceFileProperties.FileName },
                            { "Size", sourceFileProperties.FileSize },
                            { "File ID", sourceFileGUID },
                        }
                    }   
                );
```

The uploaded file look like on a screenshot.
[File uploaded to GridFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x9GC.png).
After a few days of googling, I still can understand, how to query the GridFS and get all this data.
For example, I want to download this file by "File ID".

I start with:

```
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");

        //Initializing GdridFS conection
        GridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(db);
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("fs.files");
```

I know, that I need to use GridFSFileInfo method, but I can't understand how.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

All.
The problem was solved by:

```
//Filter by Metadata property
        var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.And(
        Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Metadata["FileName"], "node-v0.12.7-x64.msi"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a more extensive code example? I feel a bit confused about how to use the version 3 of the driver and this is what I managed to come up with to get an IEnumerable<GridFSFileInfo>:

`var gridFSBucket = new GridFSBucket(this.mongoDb);
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq(fi => fi.Metadata["FileName"], filename);
var cursor = gridFSBucket.FindAsync(filter).Result;
cursor.MoveNextAsync().Wait();
return cursor.Current;
`
But this seems a bit weird to me ...